# Azure DevOps - how to make artifacts retention policy working when publishing to file share

Tags: azure-devops, artifacts, retention

I have two tasks at end of my build pipeline

```
    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: '7z'
        sevenZipCompression: 'ultra'
        archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).7z'
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
      inputs:
        targetPath: '$(Build.StagingDirectory)'
        publishLocation: 'filepath'
        fileSharePath: 'D:\Builds\some-folder'
```

What I need do or change here to make agents deleting artifacts when I delete specific build run?
Or just remove published files with retention policy?

I am using Azure DevOps with 5 self-hosted agents on this same machine.

Update:
To be clear retention policy is set but artifacts not being deleted from self-hosting machine.

Comment: I have the same issue. Could you already solve it?

Comment: @roli09 You need do it manualy
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67103788/azure-devops-how-to-make-artifacts-retention-policy-working-when-publishing-to?noredirect=1#comment118768793_67121105

Answer (score -1):

In the azure devops pipeline Retention policy, we can set the Days to keep artifacts, symbols and attachments. Normally, we set the days to thirty. Also, you can change it to other days.
[image]
Refer this doc: [Set run retention policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/policies/retention?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#set-run-retention-policies)

Comment: Retention policy is set but artifacts not being deleted from self-hosting machines.

Comment: This retention policy will help you clean the default artifact path like '/home/builder/agent/_work/r11/a'. I noticed that you publish your artifact to another place in your local machine, so we recommend you can try to create a new pipeline and clean these file manually.

Comment: What about this issue, does the answer will help you? If yes, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.